# SQL Ordenação alfabética com código html

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela que contém o campo `titulo`. Tenho uma consulta e quero ordenar alfabeticamente por ele, porém, alguns campos estão com códigos HTML, darei exemplos:

> Abate de Caprinos e Processamento da Carne
>
> Abate e Comercializa`&ccedil;&atilde;`o de Animais

No segundo exemplo, para o usuário aparece o nome correto `Abate e Comercialização de Animais`, mas no banco está na forma exibida acima.

É possível ordenar em ordem alfabética considerando o texto sem os códigos html, como texto "legível"?

Comment: Veja essa questão :  [PostgreSQL replace HTML entities function
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961992/postgresql-replace-html-entities-function). Testei a solução aqui no postgreSQL 10 e funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode contornar o problema criando mais uma coluna no seu banco de dados na qual armazena os títulos **com acentuação**.

Assim, ao fazer a ordenação, você pode utilizar esta coluna nova (`titulo_com_acentos`). Ao retornar a informação para a tela, você pode usar a coluna atual.

```
 id | titulo                                           | titulo_com_acentos
 1  | Abate e Comercializa&ccedil;&atilde;o de Animais | Abate e Comercialização de Animais
```

Este tipo de solução é bem comum quando precisamos extrair determinada informação de uma coluna na tabela mas, por algum motivo, é inviável extrair esta informação em tempo de execução. Então esta extração de informação é feita em uma etapa anterior e salva no banco de dados, sincronizada com a informação original.

Comment: Acabou que vou ter de fazer é algo parecido com isso. Ao invés de contornar o problema, na programação, onde insere no banco, vou inserir sem os códigos html todas as vezes e rodar uma rotina no sql para substituir esses códigos. Aí mantenho um campo só. Mas obrigado, sua solução resolve o problema.